# Custom YouTube Player

Tags: flash, youtube

Is it possible to hide the video content of the YouTube player (only statusbar (where is play button etc.) is visible) ? Or maybe do you know other (flash) players that have the ability to stream the YouTube movies ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at JW Player, 
http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/, it is widely used, customizable and can play YouTube videos.

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery TubePlayer plugin may be an option. If you use set the showControls property to 0 you could then implement your own markup and CSS for the controls. Alternatively you can basically have the entire embeddable player's functionality, too.

Check it out http://tikku.com/jquery-youtube-tubeplayer-plugin